# Differential form of continuity

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I hope my question is not too ridiculous, but why can differentiate a physical equation in the following manner:

$$\rho VA=\textrm{constant}$$

$$\frac{d\rho}{\rho}+\frac{dA}{A}+\frac{dV}{V}=0$$

It is the equation of continuity at steady state, and I understand that all the members are then divided by $\rho VA$ but why can we cancel $dt$ as if it was a constant?

Comment: Take the derivative of both sides (what is the derivative of a constant?) and apply the product rule to the left side. Where is this $dt$ you mention?

Comment: Well if you want to take the derivative you have to do something like $\frac{d}{dt}$ right? I know that the derivative of $\frac{d( \rho AV)}{dt}=0$ but then in the expression there will be this $dt$ term, how can I cancel a differential element?

Comment: The derivative is not with respect to t.  It should be with respect to x along the duct.

Comment: Why should the properties be constant along the duct? And also how would i be able to cancel the $dx$?

Comment: LHS: $d(\rho V A) = d(\rho)VA + \rho d(V)A + \rho Vd(A)$. RHS: $d(constant) = 0$. Now divide by $\rho VA$. See more [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function).

Comment: But can you take a derivative without making it with respect to something, i.e, $d/d()$?

Comment: You're not finding the derivative. You're finding the *differential*.

Comment: $\rho V A$ represents the mass flow rate along the duct, and, at steady state, by conservation of mass,  it is certainly going to be constant along the duct.  Each individual parameter is not necessarily going to be constant along the duct, but the product of the three will be.    So, if you take the derivative of the mass flow rate with respect to position along the duct, you get:  $$\frac{d\rho}{dx}VA+\rho\frac{dV}{dx}A+\rho V\frac{dA}{dx}=0$$, or, equivalently $$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{d\rho}{dx}+\frac{1}{V}\frac{dV}{dx}+\frac{1}{A}\frac{dA}{dx}=0$$